# Install and work with Cloud Custodian in EC2 instance (Linux)?

Tags: linux, cloudcustodian

I have executed the following command on my Linux instance:

```
yum install custodian
```

It is installed, but I don't know how to start it and use it. Can anybody helps me how can use execute yml script.

Comment: please show what you have tried.

Comment: yum install custodian

Comment: It is installed but I don't know how to start it and use it

Comment: Stackoverflow isn't a code/instruction writing service. It is for answering specific programming problems - please review the https://stackoverflow.com/tour

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `linux` We can install custodian by using commands like :

1). `virtualenv` custodian

2). for starting custodian 
   source custodian/bin/activate

3). install `cli` on it 
   pip install `cli`

4). install `c7n`
   pip install `c7n`

5). now configure user details as:
   aws configure